# How to get $P(X < x)$ and $P(X \geq x)$?

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution, stata

After doing some reading about the binomial distribution I found this about lower and upper bound probabilities

We can get the **lower tail probability** of X as:
$$P(X \leq x)=P(X=0)+...+P(X=x)$$

- **Stata:** as `binomial(n,k,p)`
- **R:** `pbinom(q, size, prob, lower.tail = TRUE)`

And the **upper tail probability** can be obtained as the complement of lower tail probability to find the area above the cutoff x-value
$$P(X>x)= 1-P(X \leq x)$$

- **Stata:** `1- binomial(n, k, p)`
- **R:** `pbinom(q, size, prob, lower.tail = FALSE)`

[image]

Am I right for the R and Stata commands?

And also how can I get these probabilities? 
Are they complementary, as upper and lower bound probabilities?

$$P(X < x)$$
$$P(X \geq x)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in `R`

From the help file `?pbinom`

> - *lower.tail*
>
> logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x].

Now if you wanted $P(X \geq x)$, this is the same as `$P(X > (x-1))$, given that you are dealing with a discrete distribution.

```
pbinom(q-1, size, prob, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

This is the same as $1 - P( X < x)$ (if you hadn't noticed already)

In the same way, if you wanted $P( X < x)$, this is the same as $P(X \leq (x-1))$.

```
pbinom(q-1, size, prob, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

here $x$ refers to the `q` argument in `pbinom`

---

## STATA

`stata` has two commands `binomial(n,k,p)`

which returns

$P(X \leq k)$

and `binomialtail(n,k, p)`

which returns

$P(X \geq k)$

So  if you wanted

$P(X < k)$

This would be

```
binomial(n, k-1, p)
```

or

```
1 - binomialtail(n, k, p)
```

If you wanted

$P(X > k)$

This would be

```
 binomialtail(n, k+1, p)
```

or

```
 1 - binomial(n, k, p)
```

Comment: Is $P(X>x-1)=P(X>x)-1$?

Comment: No, $P(X>x-1) = P(X>(x-1))$, i've edited the answer

Comment: I've added the `stata` case